# CodeIgniter - MySql: How to insert data more than one fields into the same columns in database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

How to insert data like this in a table in a database? There are two inputboxes on the form. One of them is for WeekId and the other one is for EventId. When I try to insert data to the table, the data are rewritten not exactly what I want. I mean when I insert 1, 15, 26 as eventid for weekid 1, the data is shown like below.

```
week_id   event_id
  1          26
```

The last one is shown but I want to do like below

```
week_id   event_id
  1          1
  1          15
  1          26
  1          18
  1          15
  1          10
```

How to do it? I use Codeigniter, mysql.

Comment: add the related code.

Comment: What is the name the thing that I should look for? :) Is it trigger?

Comment: If you are trying multiple records then please use text name as an array. I think same name is returning only last value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're inputting in the input field as an array. I mean, if you input 1,15,26 in eventID inputbox then you should use explode().. example:

```
$eventID=explode(",",$this->input->post('inputfield'));
$length=sizeof($eventID);
for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
//your SQL insert statement here with values $eventID[i] and $weekID
// or your insert function 
}
```

Hope this would help..

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't add a comment in your question.. Is that what you mean?